# Как в MySQL выбрать строки, значение столбца которых повторяется не более 2х раз

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется таблица

```
id|cat_id|name
 1|     1|test1
 2|     1|test2
 3|     2|test3
 4|     3|test4
 5|     3|test5
 6|     1|test6
```

Нужно сделать выборку так, чтобы в ней было не более чем 2х товаров из каждой категории. Как это сделать?

Вот ссылка на БД, для проверки
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8025044/table.sql

Comment: вы можете [добавить](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/563539/edit) в вопрос ожидаемый/результирующий "data set"?

Comment: все решилось с помощью ответа ниже. Спасибо, что откликнулись! Ура!

Answer (score 4):

Думаю проще всего это будет сделать с использованием переменных:

```
select *
  from (
        select T.*,@n:=if(@cat=cat_id,@n+1,1) as Num,@cat:=cat_id
          from test7 T,(select @n:=0,@cat:=0) A
         order by cat_id
       ) A
 where Num<=2
```

Сортировка во внутреннем подзапросе должна обязательно начинаться с cat_id, далее к ней можно добавлять другие поля, что бы регулировать какие именно из двух записей показывать.

Вариант "обычным SQL":

```
 select *
   from test7
  where id in(select max(id) from test7 group by cat_id
               union
              select min(id) from test7 group by cat_id
             )
```

Из ограничений метода: из любой группы всегда выбирается запись с минимальным и максимальным ID.

Comment: Спасибо! Работает.